# iOS App on App Store Does not Detect BTLE devices but Dev Version does

Tags: ios, permissions, bluetooth, info.plist, btle

I have an app that is able to detect BTLE devices and connect to them in the developer version. After submitting this to the app store and downloading it I'm unable to detect any devices. Are there permissions that I have to add?

I have looked at:

```
bluetooth-central
bluetooth-peripheral
```

These seem to be directed at using BT in the background. My app does not deal with background connections. When the user leaves the app it disconnects any existing communications.

and

```
bluetooth-le
```

This one seems to be to restrict the user's device to only use BT. This is an option for us but not a requirement. If it means it works then we'll add it but if they don't connect to a device that is ok as well.

I'm a little confused as to how to test this as well. If my Dev version is working but only the app store one is not I'm not sure how to test other than submitting it to the app store every time for review and testing afterwards.

Thanks!

Comment: It may sound like a silly question, but did you submit the right version to the App Store. I recently submitted an app and then found a feature was missing because they had approved an earlier build - the new build submission process in iTunesConnect seems to make it easy to submit the wrong build for approval. There isn't anything you need to do to get basic bluetooth working.

Comment: Can you see any console messages about bluetooth if you connect and monitor while it runs ?

Comment: Do you have CoreBluetooth Linked in the Frameworks step for the App Store build?